# Access to TextArea - JavaFX, Java 8

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, fxmlloader

I've got troubles with getting access to FXML TextArea.

Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextArea textArea;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
        new ClientRead().start();//creating and running new thread
    }

    void refreshTextArea(String text){
        if (text != null){
            this.textArea.setText(text);
        }
    }

}
```

ClientRead.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ClientRead extends Thread {

    public void run(){
        refreshTextArea("content");
    }

    private void refreshTextArea(String text){

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        Controller c = fxmlLoader.getController();
        c.refreshTextArea(text);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <TextArea fx:id="textArea" layoutX="39.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="130.0" prefWidth="110.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I want to get reference to `textArea` in `ClientRead` class to call `setText()` on it from another class, in another thread. 
However, I tried this method and it didn't work. I've tried to pass instance of class `Controller`, by using `this` to constructor of `ClientRead` as well, but the result was the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To sum it up it is a Minimal(small amount of code) Complete(Fully runnable) Verifiable(I can put into my IDE and run without errors) Example(Recreate your problem). There is too many thing I can't see in your code such as why your calling `new ClientRead().start();` in LoggedController which builds UI with another LoggedController as the root its confusing and cyclical. Which is why you can't debug on your own.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, as You suggested, I created MCVE. I'm new here, so thanks for tips :)

Comment: You might want to take a look to [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) tutorial in order to implement the background task properly. In other words, `ClientRead` should extend from `Task` not `Thread`, in order to avoid blocking the `Platform` thread and making the UI unresponsive.

Comment: Do not initialize `sample`in `Client`. Add a constructor to `Client` that can accept a reference to `TextArea` : `new ClientRead(textarea)`  or a reference to `Controller` : `new ClientRead(this)`